# Removing Fields From the Profile Page of Theme My Login Plugin

Tags: profiles, customization

I would like to remove fields from the profile in [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/). I want to remove everything except email and password field. I am able to hide fields using a little jQuery. But un fortunately I'm not good with it. Can someone help me how to make this? step by step?

**Update:**
I found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-my-login-hide-profile-fields-from-theme-my-login?replies=19) but i dont know how to use it:

> "This may not be the ideal approach, but I was able to hide fields
>   (and their associated labels and the parent p/div/tr element) using a
>   little jQuery, if you're familiar with that. Just target the input to
>   hide, climb up to its parent element, and hide it. This assumes that
>   the  element is nested 3 levels down from the element i
>   actually need to hide.. a  in my case. And i use a wp conditional
>   to run this code only on the 'edit-profile' page."

```
<?php
// this code goes in header.php, in the <head> section.
if(is_page('edit-profile') ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // hide fields (the entire <tr>)
            jQuery('#id-of-field').parent().parent().parent().hide();
        });
    </script>
<?php }
```

Comment: Are you talking about the plugin [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/)? If not, there are [plenty of threads](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bprofile+%2Bfields) in this Stack about how to do this using a filter hook...

Comment: i want to hide fields in profile page at frontend. like jabber yahoo im. actually i want to remove everything but the password and email field.

Comment: If you are talking about the plugin, have you checked this page http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/templates/ ?

Comment: yes i looked that page and read all support. i found this code but i dont know how to use it: `<?php
// this code goes in header.php, in the <head> section.
if(is_page('edit-profile') ) { ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // hide fields (the entire <tr>)
   jQuery('#id-of-field').parent().parent().parent().hide();
  });
 </script>
<?php }`

Comment: 1907, I know that learning a programming language **and** a foreign language is challenging and I congratulate you for your efforts! But I already mentioned to you that reading the FAQ will enhance your experience in this Stack and still you don't have the [*Analytical Badge*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/77/analytical)... :(

Comment: brasofilo, i am learning :) thank you for your help. the pleasure of doing it by alone is priceless. i know i am pressing hard. sorry for that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [link](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/templates/) I provided in the comments:

> All of the templates located within
>   /wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/templates are easily customizable.
>   Just ***simply pick any template you wish to edit, copy it to your***
>   ***current theme’s directory and edit it as you wish***. Theme My Login will
>   always look for templates in your current theme’s directory first,
>   before loading it’s own templates.

So:

- create a Page Template using the file `page.php` of your theme as model and put a template header

> ```
> <?php
> /*
> Template Name: Profile Page
> */
> ```

- copy **all the code** from `/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/templates/profile-form.php`
- paste it in your new template, substituting the loop block:

> ```
> <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
>   <?php /* code code code */ ?>
> <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
> ```

- now you can customize everything you need

Answer (score 2):

@brasofilo is nearly there but there is a better way to do this.

Goto your theme folder and create a folder called 'theme-my-login'.

Copy any file from the theme-my-login/templates folder into this new folder.

The plugin will first check the theme's folder and then the template folder.

This is standard practice in WP for dealing with template files.

EG.

to edit the profile page copy /plugins/theme-my-plugin/templates/profile-form.php to /themes/child-theme/theme-my-login/profile-form.php

Et voila - you can now amend the template in your theme folder.